# How can I show image in laptop screen, with appropriate image rotation and perspective?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have been searching from last two days on internet, I have checked many source codes on net but none of them has provided the result I want.

The image rotation would have perspective but still there would be no changes in the heights of both left and right sides of an image.[image]

I want to set image inside the laptop screen

Please help me out, Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your question, but Isn't that an "oximoronic" request? I'm assuming a 3D perspective is what you are talking about. If you are on a 2 dimensional screen, it has to change the width and height to create the depth field.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to 2D pespective drawing of a laptop screen (on an iOS device?) and put a 2D image on that screen, but with the image transformed so its perspective looks correct on the laptop screen, right?

What you need to do is to add an image view on top of your laptop image view. Lets call it laptopScreenImageView.

Then apply a CATransform3D to that the laptopScreenImageView's layer.

The trick to get 3D perspective out of a CALayer is to modify the .m34 value of the transform. Typically you set the .m34 value to a very small negative number, somewhere around -1/200 to -1/500 (the denominator in the fraction is the z coordinate of the "eye position" for viewing the perspective image, in pixels, or how many pixels "above" the image the viewer's eye should seem to be. I don't fully understand it, to be honest. I fiddle with the .m34 value until I get something that looks right.)

Alternately you could try adding a CATransformLayer to your laptop image view's layer, and then adding a CALayer containing your image as a sublayer of the CATransformLayer. I haven't used `CATransformLayer`s before, but the docs say they are supposed to support layers with 3D perspective, giving you the same effect as modifying the .m34 component of a layer's transform.